# Delphi get components in loop

Tags: delphi, loops, components

I have pagecontrol with 3 pages. On each page I have control for example TEdit with name's edt1 (on first page),etd2 (on second page),edt3 (on third page).

I want to iterate  for each and set a text value.

Something like :

```
 for j := 0 to pages.count-1 do
begin
edt[j].text:= 'something ' + IntToStr(j);
end;
```

but it doesn't work this way

Comment: Iterate through the children on the tabsheet, Controls[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for i := 0 to pages.Count - 1 do
begin
    TEdit(FindComponent('edt' + IntToStr(i))).Text := 'something';
end;
```

You should add some error-checking, in case `FindComponent` returns `nil`.